# Add new status for task in Maniphest (Phabricator)?

Tags: phabricator

How can I add a new status in Phabricator's Maniphest? I want to add `In Progress`.

- The feature seems to be available: https://secure.phabricator.com/T1812
- But no documentation on how to use it: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/ (or I have missed it)

---

Yes thanks, something like this gets me there:
https://my.phab.com/config/edit/maniphest.statuses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config -> Applications -> Maniphest -> maniphest.priorities